# How to load images on startup

Tags: java, loading

I want to load all my game's images on the game's startup and have a loading bar to show it's progress. I already know how to create and display the loading bar, but I can't figure out how to load the images, and then add the image's frames to it's array.

Not using SLick

Comment: How big are your images? Are you sure they won't be loaded pretty much instantaneously, thus not requiring a progress bar?

Answer (score 1):

Loading an image in Java is easy:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
```

But I have no idea what you mean by "add the image's frames to it's array".

You are not using Slick, but are you using LWJGL? If so, you need to create a Texture from this image before you can use it. Do you need help with that?